# Find out if guessed number is higher, lower or equal to Random number, or guessed before etc

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm developing a guess number in ASP.NET and send a guessed number from a textbox to this method:

```
public Outcome MakeGuess(int guess)
    {
        //Most of this code can be wrong
        if (Number > 1 && Number < 100)
        {
            foreach (int number in PreviousGuesses)
            {

            }
            if (Number == guess)
            {
                return Outcome.Correct;
            }
            else if (Number < guess)
            {
                return Outcome.High;
            }
            else if (Number > guess)
            {
                return Outcome.Low;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            throw ArgumentOutOfRangeException;
        }
```

And have an Enum who looks like this:

```
enum Outcome
    {
        Indefinite,
        Low,
        High,
        Correct,
        NoMoreGuesses,
        PreviousGuess
    }
```

I should find out if the guess is too low, too high, right guess, an earlier made guess (checking from a list), or if the user has used all tries(checking a constant). I Started trying but i'm stuck! My code may be wrong.

Comment: Is this Homework? Also, can you ask a specific question or describe what the exact problem is?

Comment: What is PreviousGuesses and how does it store them?

Comment: not sure i completely  understand about previous guess. but other than previous guess it seems good. could you please explain more about previous guess? for example you are comparing against it or just displaying?

Comment: Also, what is the deal with the empty foreach loop?

Comment: @HerrNilsson All questions end with a `?`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Store your guesses in a list

```
private List<int> _guesses = new List<int>();
```

After calling `MakeGuess(guess)` add the guess to the list

```
_guesses.Add(guess);
```

Instead of the `foreach` loop do this

```
if (_guesses.Contains(guess)) {
    return outcome.PreviousGuess;
}
```

---

The last `else` can be simplified from

```
else if (Number > guess) {
    return Outcome.Low;
}
```

to

```
else {
    return Outcome.Low;
}
```

since this is the only possible case remaining.

---

I would simplify the method further

```
public Outcome MakeGuess(int guess)
{
    if (_guesses.Contains(guess)) {
        return outcome.PreviousGuess;
    }
    if (guess == Number) {
        return Outcome.Correct;
    }   
    if (guess > Number) {
        return Outcome.High;   
    }   
    return Outcome.Low;             }
}
```

The `else` keyword is not necessary because the `return` statements end the method execution if a case applies.

The error handling should not be necessary if you calculate the random numbers correctly. You should not trap programming errors with error handling; instead, correct the errors! Error handling makes sense when calling a method can lead to an exception. An example is opening a file that might not exist or might be locked or the like. In libraries used by other persons, it makes sense to check if the parameters passed to a method are correct and to throw an exception if not.